# getting XML from Oracle Tables

Tags: xml, oracle

When i run

```
SELECT XMLElement("product", 
                  XMLAttributes(fp.col2 AS "attr2",fp.col4 as "attr4",fp.col5 as "attr5",fp.col6 as "attr6")
                  XMLElement(SELECT (XMLElement("dataset",
                                    XMLAttributes(ds.col3 AS "attr3")
                                    FROM Table2 ds
                                   WHERE fp.col1 = ds.col1 and fp.col2 = ds.col2 and ds.col2='ABC')) )
                  )
FROM Table2 fp
WHERE fp.col1 = 'XYZ'
```

I get error

```
ORA-00917: missing comma
00917. 00000 -  "missing comma"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 5 Column: 18
```

I am not able to understand why

I am expecting output like

```
<product>
  <dataset></dataset>
</product>
```

also can you point me to tutorials / examples where xml is generated from joiing multiple tables. I need to have a closer look at syntax.

Most of the examples i searched for had xml generated from single table ( employee)

Comment: seems like an error to me ... i am new to XMLAttribute , XMLElement , etc .... do i need to use XMLAgg ? can you give me link to a good tutorial ... not looking for simple ones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---EDIT---

I've modified your query. It should work:

```
SELECT XMLElement("product"
  , XMLAttributes(fp.col2 AS "attr2",fp.col4 as "attr4",fp.col5 as "attr5",fp.col6 as "attr6")
  , (
    SELECT XMLElement("dataset"
      , XMLAttributes(ds.col3 AS "attr3")
    )
    FROM Table2 ds
    WHERE fp.col1 = ds.col1 and fp.col2 = ds.col2 and ds.col2='ABC'
  )
)
FROM Table2 fp
WHERE fp.col1 = 'XYZ';
```

In your query there is unnecessary `XMLElement` clause (second one) and before subquery the comma is missing.

Comment: on adding same, still the issue persists ... not sure if i need to use XMLAgg ... looking for more examples

Comment: Thanks KPater87 it worked now , before i accept your answer ... can you point me to good tutorial ... where i need to get parent child elements from joining different tables .... i need to create more complex queries having 5 children and 3 levels of nesting

Comment: I don't know good tutorial. But you should start by reading the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e23094/xdb13gen.htm#ADXDB1620). Additionaly to creating big queries the clause `WITH` is quite useful. Good luck!

Comment: sorry man , my mistake .... i only get product from above query not child elements dataset ...not sure data is issue or syntax

Comment: Syntax is good. Maybe in your database there is nothing to display as dataset (with this conditions). You should know your data!

Comment: in above if there are more than one children i.e. <dataset> then will the query give error ?

Comment: Yes, if you have more than one <dataset> you can use [XMLAGG](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions215.htm) function.

Comment: thanks i have a more complicated scenario  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17723725/getting-xml-from-five-different-oracle-tables can you help