# Getting XML from Five Different Oracle Tables

Tags: xml, oracle

I need to get xml like

```
<dataset code="123" title="" pubcode="456" minrows="0">
    <schema code="s1" /> <!-- can be one -->
    <rowset code="rs1" /> <!-- can be one -->
    <sorter>
        <!-- field can be MORE than one -->
        <field name="field1" order="o1"/>
        <field name="field2" order="o2"/>
    </sorter>
    <!-- filter can be MORE than one -->
    <filter type="filter1" value="val1" />
    <filter type="filter2" value="val2" />
</dataset>
```

Where each tag corresponds to a a separate table. 
And each attribute in that tag is a column in the corresponding table
Have written below sql for same

```
 SELECT  XMLELEMENT(NAME "dataset",
                       XMLAttributes(ds.DataSet_Code AS "code",ds.DataSet_Title as "title",ds.pub_code as "pubcode",ds.Min_Rows as "minrowss"),
                       XMLFOREST(  
                            (SELECT XMLElement("schema", XMLAttributes(fs.schema_code AS "code"))
                            FROM File_Schema fs WHERE fr.dataset_code = ds.dataset_code),
                            (SELECT XMLElement("rowset", XMLAttributes(fr.rowset_code AS "code")) FROM File_RowSet fr
                              WHERE fr.dataset_code = ds.dataset_code),
                            (SELECT XMLELEMENT(NAME "sorter",
                                        XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(NAME "field",
                                                            XMLATTRIBUTES(fsf.field_name AS "name",fsf.field_order AS "order")
                                                          )
                                                )
                                        )
                            FROM File_sorter_field fsf WHERE fsf.dataset_code=ds.dataset_code),
                            (SELECT XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(NAME "filter", XMLATTRIBUTES(type AS "type",value AS "value")))
                                        FROM File_Filter ff where ff.dataset_code=ds.dataset_code)

                    ))
FROM File_Product fp , File_DataSet ds
WHERE fp.File_Name = ds.File_Name and fp.File_Name = 'abc' and ds.dataset_code ='123' ;
```

for which I get error like below

```
    ORA-19208: parameter 1 of function XMLFOREST must be aliased 19208. 00000 
  - "parameter %s of function %s must be aliased" *Cause: The indicated parameter 
  of the XML generation function has not been aliased, although it is an expression.
   *Action: Specify an alias for the expression using the AS clause. 
   Error at Line: 19 Column: 5
```

any help appreciated

**as per KPater87 modified query to**

```
SELECT  XMLELEMENT(NAME "dataset",
                       XMLAttributes(ds.DataSet_Code AS "code",ds.DataSet_Title as "title",ds.pub_code as "pubcode",ds.Min_Rows as "minrowss"),
                       XMLConcat(  
                            SELECT XMLElement("schema", XMLAttributes(fs.schema_code AS "code"))
                            FROM File_Schema fs WHERE fs.dataset_code = ds.dataset_code,
                            SELECT XMLElement("rowset", XMLAttributes(fr.rowset_code AS "code")) FROM File_RowSet fr
                              WHERE fr.dataset_code = ds.dataset_code,
                            SELECT XMLELEMENT(NAME "sorter",
                                        XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(NAME "field",
                                                            XMLATTRIBUTES(fsf.field_name AS "name",fsf.field_order AS "order")
                                                          )
                                                )
                                        )
                            FROM File_sorter_field fsf WHERE fsf.dataset_code=ds.dataset_code,
                            SELECT XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(NAME "filter", XMLATTRIBUTES(type AS "type",value AS "value")))
                                        FROM File_Filter ff where ff.dataset_code=ds.dataset_code 

                    ))
FROM File_DataSet ds
WHERE ds.File_Name = 'abc' and ds.dataset_code ='123' ;
```

still get error

ORA-00936: missing expression
00936. 00000 -  "missing expression"
*Cause:
*Action:
Error at Line: 4 Column: 28

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problems in your code:

1. As @stevo wrote: unnecessary comma
2. Inside `XMLForest` in the first `SELECT` statement wrong alias in the `WHERE` part
3. You shouldn't use `XMLForest`, you should use [XMLConcat](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e23094/xdb13gen.htm#i1032050)
4. Joining two tables in the main `SELECT` is unnecessary. After small modification: change `WHERE` part to `WHERE  ds.File_Name = 'abc' and ds.dataset_code ='123'` table `File_Product` is nowhere used.

Comment: modified the query as per your suggestion (updated question) doesnt seem to help

Comment: Now the problem is that you removed brackets inside `XMLConcat`. It should stay there. Each subquery should be inside brackets.

Comment: One question ... what's the difference between XMLConcat & XMLForest When to use which one

Comment: It is well descirbed in the Oracle documentation: [XMLForset](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions244.htm): XMLForest converts each of its argument parameters to XML, and then returns an XML fragment that is the concatenation of these converted arguments., [XMLConcat](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions240.htm): XMLConcat takes as input a series of XMLType instances, concatenates the series of elements for each row, and returns the concatenated series.

Comment: Also at present my xml output is not formatted (new lines and indentation) , Ideally i want to format the XML output as a std xml document .... and write it to a file ... I want to do this in a stored procedure ( dont think using java will be wise ) ... will appreciate your input on this ... my ques is how can i do this (formatting & write a xml file) in A stored Procedure

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem is that on line 16

```
FROM File_Filter ff where ff.dataset_code=ds.dataset_code) ,
```

the comma at the end means Oracle is expecting another expression before 
the )) on line 18.

Comment: but that is because of separating the forest element... XMLFOREST(  (SELECT ... FROM ...),(SELECT ... FROM ...),(SELECT ... FROM ...),(SELECT ... FROM ...),(SELECT ... FROM ...)) ... i dont think it will be wise to remove one and keep others

Comment: The comma separates the previous expression from the next expression. If there isn't a next one, you don't need the comma.

Comment: after removing comma i get error like ORA-00931: missing identifier
00931. 00000 -  "missing identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 15 Column: 28

Comment: i think error was with the last comma after removing it i get ORA-19208: parameter 1 of function XMLFOREST must be aliased
19208.  00000 -  "parameter %s of function %s must be aliased"
*Cause:    The indicated parameter of the XML generation function has not been aliased, although it is an expression.
*Action:   Specify an alias for the expression using the AS clause.
Error at Line: 19 Column: 5

Comment: In the first select inside XMLFOREST you are selecting data from table with alias `fs` but you are using in he where statement `fr` alias. Maybe it can help.

Comment: thanks for the catch , i changed FR to FS , still same error at same line number

Comment: i removed extra brackets XMLFOREST( SELECT ... FROM ...,SELECT ... FROM ...,SELECT ... FROM ...,SELECT ... FROM ...,SELECT ... FROM ...) now i get     ORA-00936: missing expression
00936. 00000 -  "missing expression"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 4 Column: 28